# How To Filter Out Code-Golf tagged questions

Tags: support

**The problem:**

I am interested on coding challenges and puzzles on this site, but *not* in Code-Golf. However, code-golf questions appear to be over 95% of the threads on the main forum, and make it very hard to find any questions that are *not* about code golf.

I have already added [code-golf] to my Ignore list, but that doesn't keep them out of my feed, it just makes them harder to read and it is still hard to find the non-code-golf threads (only 2 on the first page today and hard to distinguish).  I have added two Watched tags for other types of challenges, but I haven't seen enough non code-golf questions to know what all of these tags are (and that still doesn't clean up my feed).

I have tried to make a Filter for this, but there doesn't appear to be any option for "Exclude this Tag".  I have also spent some time and effort trying to find a previous question about this here but searches like "Filter Out Code Golf" just return every [code-golf] challenge with the word "Filter" in it.

I did find [this meta question](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350/is-there-a-way-to-easily-find-questions-that-arent-code-golf), but it has no solution and is from 13 years ago.

**The Question:**

So, 13 years later, is there any solution to this problem?  I suppose that I could go into the SE Data Explorer and write a custom query for this, but *yeesh*, not exactly a user-friendly solution for regularly looking for code-challenges, plus few users of this site are likely to know how to do that.

A potential future solution to this might be to create a [not-code-golf] tag and encourage it's use, a similar suggestion at the previous question seems to have been downvoted.

Answer (score 10):

### Searching for posts without code golf

You can search for [`-[code-golf]`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=-%5Bcode-golf%5D) to find all questions that do not have the [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) tag.

[image]

### Ignoring code-golf questions always

[image]

If you never want to see questions tagged code golf then you can add it to your "ignored tags". see the image above.

Make sure you select "Hide questions" and not "grey out" so that they don't pollute your feed at all.

Comment: Wow thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: More usefully, search for [`is:q -[code-golf]`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+-%5Bcode-golf%5D) to get a list of non-code-golf *questions*.